# Window location hashtag syntax error not reading after question mark

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which works fine if you land on the page with a hashtag and text following it like this `#dashboard` - its suppose to land on the hashtag `#whatever` and scroll to where ever that section is on load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // *only* if we have anchor on the url
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var hashname = $(window.location.hash);

    // smooth scroll to the anchor id
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: hashname.offset().top - 75
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

But when you land on a URL like this

`http://domain.com/#dasboard?utm_source=hubspot&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=stackoverflow`

it outputs this error `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:`

**It doesn't read anything after the `?` mark**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hashtag is an automatically hyperlinked search term. You do not have a hashtag, you have a [fragment identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), but you've implemented it incorrectly.

The fragment identifier comes **after** the query string in a URL, not before it.

The browser is parsing `#dasboard?utm_source=hubspot&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=stackoverflow` as your selector and hitting an error because you have a `?` in it.

Comment: so you're saying the hashtag should be at the end of the query string? like this? `/?utm_source=hubspot&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=stackoverflow#dashboard` ?

Comment: @BryanBarrera — Aside from it not being a hashtag, yes.